# How to compile programs that use term.h?

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gcc, c

I try to compile the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>

//#include "/usr/include/term.h"

void clear_screen(void) {
    if (!cur_term) {
        int result;
        setupterm( NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &result );
    if (result <= 0)
        return;
    }

    putp( tigetstr( "clear" ) );
}

int main(void) {
    puts("I am going to clear the screen");
    sleep(1);
    clear_screen();
    puts("Screen Cleared");
    sleep(1);
    clear_screen();

    return 0;

}
```

This program tests a function that uses the `term.h` header file to clear the terminal screen.
I have installed all the libraries needed: `libncurses5` and `libncurses5-dev` and when I compile the program with or without the `-lncurses`, `-lcurses` and `-lterminfo` parameters to the `gcc` compiler I get the above output:

```
In file included from clear_screen_UNIX.c:5:0:
clear_screen_UNIX.c:9:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
 void clear_screen(void) {
      ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c: In function ‘main’:
clear_screen_UNIX.c:23:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
              ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c:26:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
              ^
```

Moreover, when I explicitly include the `term.h` header using its full path `/usr/include/term.h` I get this as the output:

```
In file included from clear_screen_UNIX.c:7:0:
/usr/include/term.h:125:21: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
 #define CUR cur_term->type.
                     ^
/usr/include/term.h:202:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘CUR’
 #define clear_screen                   CUR Strings[5]
                                        ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c:9:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘clear_screen’
 void clear_screen(void) {
      ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c: In function ‘main’:
clear_screen_UNIX.c:23:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
              ^
clear_screen_UNIX.c:26:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  clear_screen();
              ^
```

According to the above, the `term.h` header has some mistakes inside, something I do not believe.

So do I need to install some more packages or configure some settings for the code to compile successfully?

PS:

- The code example is from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/#POSIX)
- My Ubuntu version is 14.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `clear_screen` is a macro:

```
$ grep clear_screen /usr/include/term.h
#define clear_screen                   CUR Strings[5]
```

You will have to use some other name, like the linked page does:

```
void Clear_screen (void)
```

The compiler messages also state this:

```
clear_screen_UNIX.c:9:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘clear_screen’
```

That's why the errors seem to be in `term.h` - the macro expansion leads there.

Comment: That's it. The program has been successfully compiled now and it is also working as expected.